# как положить в список перечень value с помощью driver.find_elements_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Имеется html :

```
<div class="snglCrncyCrss">
<div class="float_lang_base_1">
        <select id="symbols" onchange="change_result();" class="newInput selectBox">
               <option value="22"  >AED - UAE Dirham</option>
               <option value="93"  >AFN - Afghanistan Afghani</option>
               <option value="58"  >ALL - Albanian Lek</option>
```

мне нужно с помощью python получить список value 
вот мой код :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.investing.com/currencies/single-currency-crosses')
curlisy = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div/div/select[contains(@id, "symbols")]/option/attribute::value’)
```

моя цель - в curlisy получить [22, 93, 58]
но вместо этого я получаю ошибку selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Attr value="22»]

в плагине для хрома XPath  - мое выражение работает и выдает искомый список. Selenium я использую потому, что затем по этому списку мне нужно кликать...

PS. я только начал изучать selenium

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Короче вот как сработало:

```
curlisy = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//select[contains(@id, "symbols")]/option')


for l in curlisy:
    print (l.get_attribute('value'))
```